# There is a way to determine error of an interpolation outside of the given range

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I'm trying to think about this problem:

Given a set of points $x_i$, such that $x_i \in [a,b]$ and the value on this points of an function $f(x_i)%$ is given too,we know that the derivative is bounded

$$f^{(n)}(x) \leq g(n)
$$

but here we impose that this inequality holds for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so if I try to interpolate this function by Lagrange's polynomials what I can say about the interpolation error in a point $y \ge b$.

Well, but I know that for Lagrange's polynomials I can say that

$$|f(x) - P(x)| \leq |\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}\prod_{i=0}^{n}(x-x_i)|$$

The problem is that this hold for $x \in [a,b]$. So my question is that if I can extend this error's inequality using the bounded derivative in all domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula is valid for all $x$, the point $ξ$ then belongs to the interval or convex hull containing $x_0,...,x_n$ and $x$. See the proof https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lagrange_Polynomial_Approximation, there are no restrictions to the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: Hey, the prove supose that $x_i \in I$, and $x \in I$ and then exist $\xi$ in the interval spanned by $x_i$. Let me give an example, if you know ten values in the interval $[0,1]$ what is an estimave for the error of $f(2)$

Comment: The same formula, only that you need to take the maximum of $|f^{(n+1)}(ξ)|$ over the interval $ξ\in[0,2]$. Of course the domain $I$ where $f$ is defined and sufficiently often differentiable has to include the interval $[0,2]$.